# Does "ret" stall the pipeline?

Tags: x86, return, pipeline

Since the `ret` instruction is an indirect call, does the `ret` instruction on x86 stall the pipeline, or is it somehow optimized to behave like a more direct call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Intel Optimization Reference Manual, the branch prediction unit contains a Return Stack Buffer precisely to predict `ret` instructions (section 2.2.2.1) more accurately. The instruction queueing and decode unit also tracks changes in the stack pointer to improve decoding bandwidth (section 2.2.2.5).

In more detail, section 3.4.1.4 describes some "rules", mostly directed to compiler writers, to benefit from inlining, calls & returns - the most relevant is probably that a near/far call must be paired with a near/far return, which means pushing the return address on the stack and jumping to the callee is not recommended. Also, the call depth is recommended to not exceed 16 nested calls (the size of the RSB).

If those rules are followed, you can effectively treat them like indirect branches during branch selection (section 3.4.1.6), with everything that implies. You will most likely never encounter a stall on a `ret`, except on pathological cases or self-modifying code.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't realize this was documented in the optimization manual! Thanks so much for the detailed answer!